# Solution of Burgers equation with some initial data

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, finite-difference-method

Consider the Burgers equation 
$$\partial_t u + \partial_x\left(u^2/2 \right) = 0,     \quad u(0, x) = u_0(x).$$

```
eq = D[u[t, x], t] + D[u[t,x]^2/2, x] == 0
```

How can I use Mathematica to get the (unique entropy) solution that has the Cantor staircase function as initial data $u_0 = F_C$?

And how can I plot this solution?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible becaus $\partial_x(u^2/2)$ is a singular measure (neither absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure nor a countable sum of Dirac measures). But you may try to use `NDSolve` with the first few iterates of the piecewise-linear functions that converge to the Cantor staircase function. In the (for me) best imaginable universe, the solutions might converge in a very weak sense to your desired solution so that you might get an impression of how it looks like.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck -- solving the Burgers equation? setting up the Cantor's staircase?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: Actually, since the finite iterates $F_n$ that are usually used to approximate $F_C$ are piecewise-linear and monotonically increasing, it should be possible to solve Burger's equation analytically in a piewise polynomial way. Due to shocks, the polynomial patches have to be truncated also in time and I expect that first time $T_n$ for which the a shock emerges arises with $u_0 = F_n$ converges to $T_n \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$. So, things will become _really_ complicated.

Comment: @ChrisK If I take the initial condition as "CantorStaircase[x]", it seems that I don't get any output (I don't know why). And I don't know how to set up the "$n$-th approximation" of the Cantor function with Mathematica.

Comment: @Zyl If you have `NDSolve` working for other initial conditions, post your code here so people don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @ChrisK It seems that it doesn't work at all: it appears that the error is with the equation being nonlinear. That seems strange though. Unfortunately I'm not very experienced with Mathematica.

Comment: A Burger equation is part of the nonlinear FEM verification tests: [Convection—FEM-NL-Transient-1D-Single-Convection-0001](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/NonlinearFiniteElementVerificationTests.html#1129285755) or in the help system under `FEMDocumentation/tutorial/NonlinearFiniteElementVerificationTests#\
1129285755`

Answer (score 9):

Here is how to obtain the "$n$-th approximating function of `CantorStaircase`.

```
ClearAll[f];
f[0] = x \[Function] x;
f[n_Integer?Positive] := f[n] = x \[Function] Evaluate[PiecewiseExpand[
      Piecewise[{
        {0, x <= 0},
        {1/2 f[n - 1][3 x], 0 <= x <= 1/3},
        {1/2, 1/3 <= x <= 2/3},
        {1/2 + 1/2 f[n - 1][3 x - 2], 2/3 <= x <= 1},
        {1, 1 <= x}
        }]]];
```

**Dislcaimer:** *As nonlinear FEM is involved in the following, this will work only with _Mathematica_ version 12 or later.*

Next step is to solve the PDE numerically. This is a hyperbolic PDE of firsts order which is notorious for its shocks. So we use some diffusion to obtain a stable numerical scheme (so `ϵ` converging to `0`, we will obtain the viscousity sol). The second, very important trick is to general a spacial discretization that has the nondifferentiable points of the initial conditions contained in its vertex list.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
sign = 1;
ϵ = 0.0001;
T = 1;
n = 5;
nElements = 10 3^n;
Ω = ToElementMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> Partition[Subdivide[-1., 2., nElements], 1],
   "MeshElements" -> {LineElement[Partition[Range[nElements + 1], 2, 1]]},
   "MeshOrder" -> 1
   ];
sol = NDSolveValue[
  {
   D[u[t, x], t] - ϵ D[u[t, x], x, x] + D[u[t, x]^2/2, x] == 0,
   u[0, x] == sign f[n][x]
   },
  u, {t, 0, T}, x ∈ Ω
  ];

Plot3D[sol[t, x], {x, -1/2, 3/2}, {t, 0, T},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "t"},
 PlotRange -> sign {-0.1, 1.1},
 NormalsFunction -> None,
 PlotPoints -> {200, 200},
 ViewPoint -> {- sign 1.3, -2.4, 2.}
 ]
```

[image]

We can nicely see the rarefaction waves. Shock waves can only be observed after setting `sign` to a negative value; here is the plot for `sign = -1`:

[image]

Comment: @Zyl  `sign` flips the initial condition from $F_C$ to $-F_C$. Rarefaction waves are the "opposite" of shocks. Please, inform yourself on Burger's equation for more details.

Comment: Thank you. In addition to the previous three questions ( **1.** Do you get anything by setting the initial data as "CantorStaircase[x]"? **2.** If not, is it possible to have a table with multiple plots (for different and bigger values of n? **3.** Can you get from Mathematica an explicit expression of the solution at time 1? It kind of looks like a step function.), a fourth one occurred: **4.** What happens for longer times, for example, up to $t=3$?

Comment: **1.** Just try it. **2.** You're free to try it yourself. **3.** Not with `NDSolve`. As I told you before, it is principally possible to solve the ODE exactly for `f[n]` as initial condition. But that's simply to much work for me. Try it yourself! **4.** Again, you are free to try it yourself.

Comment: I'd gladly try myself, but I don't have a newer version of Mathematica to make the nonlinear FEM run.

Comment: Maybe you have access to _Mathematica_ online? That runs already under version 12.

Comment: I don't think I do.