# Problem with definition of boundary problem

Tags: differential-equations, finite-difference-method

My procedure for solving coupled 1 + 1 (spatial + temporal) PDE system:

(Note: I have graphs of the correct solution with which I compare my result. See figure below text.)

1) I determine the initial conditions (initial functions $u_{ini}$-more functions), numerically (NDSolve) I find the necessary functions. In this solution using NDSolve, I enter the initial condition as $u_{ini} [dx] == du$, where dx is a small value (although in theory there should be $u_{ini} [0] == 0$).

2) I will use the resulting functions as initial conditions for solving the PDE using the "MethodOfLines" method. However, there is uncertainty about how to practically set the boundary conditions at the point $x = 0$, when at this point I do not have a solution of the initial functions $u_{ini}$.

Attempts:
a) First I set the initial condition as $u[x, 0] == u_{ini} [x]$ and the boundary condition as $u [dx, t] == ​​u_{ini} [dx]$ (I identified dx as zero, however $dx$ and $u_{ini} [dx]$ were not zero). This led to the right solution, which, however, diverged over time with the right solution and subsequently destabilized (began to oscillate). At first glance, I noticed that the main difference between my solution and the correct solution is only around $x = 0$ when the functions of the correct solution go to zero faster, while my solution always went to the value $u_{ini} [dx]$. I GUESS, that this is the problem with my solution. Do you agree?

b) As a second attempt, I added a point to the initial functions $u_{ini}$ at the beginning, ie point $u_{ini} [0] = 0$, and then when solving, I entered the initial conditions $u [x, 0] == u_{ini} [x]$ and the boundary conditions as $u [0, t ] == u_{ini} [0] (= 0)$. This attempt by NDSolve and "MethodOfLines" did not solve with issue warning that 1/0 infinity appears there.

Does anyone have any tricks on how to set it all up so that I get the right non-oscillating solution?

[image]
Blue, orange go in time, solid lines are correct solutions, dashed is my solution coming from the procedure a). You can see the beginning of oscillation in orange "time".

CODE:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
c = 2.99792*10^10; gr = 6.67323*10^-8; m0 = 
 1.672621*10^-24*gr/c^2; grc = gr/c^2; Ms0 = 1.98855*10^33; Ms = 
 Ms0*gr/c^2; R0 = 10^8; dr = (1/(4 \[Pi]))^(1/3);
rhs1[r_, h_] = -(gr/
   r^2) (h + p[r]/c^2) (m[r] + 4 \[Pi]*r^3 p[r]/c^2) (1 - (
    2 m[r]*gr)/(r*c^2))^-1;(*TOV*)
rhs2[r_, en_] = 4 \[Pi]*en*r^2; 
rhs3[r_, ro_] = 4 \[Pi]*ro*r^2 (1 - (2*m[r]*gr)/(r*c^2))^(-1/2);
(*____________________________________________________________________\
__*)
(*Guess on kp - destability from equilibrium factor decreasing P due \
to k constant*)
(*----------------------------------------------------------------------*)
\

kp = 36; dkp = kp/100; MP = 10*10^2;
(*g0=5/3;rho0=0.56*10^13;ep0=3.64*10^18;e0=rho0(1+ep0/c^2);pc=kp*(g0-\
1)*rho0*ep0;*)
(*g0=5/3;rho0=8*10^14;ep0=3.64*10^18;e0=rho0(1+ep0/c^2);pc=kp*(g0-1)*\
rho0*ep0;*)
g0 = 5/3; rho0 = 0.557*10^13; ep0 = 3.64*10^18; e0 = 
 rho0 (1 + ep0/c^2); pc = kp*(g0 - 1)*rho0*ep0;
k = pc/rho0^g0; fro1[r_] = (p[r]/k)^(1/g0); 
e[r_] = fro1[r] + (p[r]/c^2)/(
  g0 - 1); rhs10 = -(gr/
   dr^2) (e0 + pc/c^2) (e0 + 4 \[Pi]*dr^3 pc/c^2) (1 - (2 e0*gr)/(
    dr*c^2))^-1;
{fp0, fm0, fmu0} = 
  NDSolveValue[{p'[r] == rhs1[r, e[r]], m'[r] == rhs2[r, e[r]], 
    mu'[r] == rhs3[r, fro1[r]], p[dr] == pc - rhs10, 
    m[dr] == rho0 + (pc/c^2)/(g0 - 1), mu[dr] == rho0, 
    WhenEvent[p[r]/pc < 10^-6, "StopIntegration"]}, {p, m, mu}, {r, 
    dr, R0}];


(*____________________________________________________________________\
______*)
(*Loop for calculation of kp (pc) (careful on initial values-has to \
be same as above!)*)
(*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*)
\

M0 = 21; kp = 6; dkp = kp/10; pocet = 0; M1 = 0; Abs[M0 - M1]/M0;
Do[ep0 = kp*3.64*10^18; pc = (g0 - 1)*rho0*ep0; k = pc/rho0^g0;
  fro1[r_] = (p[r]/k)^(1/g0); e[r_] = fro1[r] + (p[r]/c^2)/(g0 - 1); 
  rhs10 = -(gr/
     dr^2) (e0 + pc/c^2) (e0 + 4 \[Pi]*dr^3 pc/c^2) (1 - (2 e0*gr)/(
      dr*c^2))^-1;
  {fpr0, fmr0, fmur0} = 
   NDSolveValue[{p'[r] == rhs1[r, e[r]], m'[r] == rhs2[r, e[r]], 
     mu'[r] == rhs3[r, fro1[r]], p[dr] == pc - rhs10, 
     m[dr] == rho0 + (pc/c^2)/(g0 - 1), mu[dr] == rho0, 
     WhenEvent[p[r]/pc < 10^-20, "StopIntegration"]}, {p, m, mu}, {r, 
     dr, R0}(*,AccuracyGoal\[Rule]25*)];
  R = fpr0[[1, 1, 2]]; M1 = fmr0[R]/Ms0; MU1 = fmur0[R]/Ms0;
  (*Print[{M1,R,fpr0[R],Abs[M0-M1]/M0,pocet,kp}];*)
  If[Abs[M0 - MU1]/M0 < 
    10^-5, {Print[{"kone", M1, Abs[M0 - M1]/M0, pocet, kp}], Break[]}];
  If[M0 > MU1, kp = kp + dkp, dkp = 0.6 dkp; kp = kp - dkp];, {pocet, 
   1, 200}];
frhor0[r_] = (fpr0[r]/k)^(1/g0); 
e[r_] = frhor0[r] + (fpr0[r]/c^2)/(g0 - 1);
R00 = fpr0[[1, 1, 2]]/100;

(*________________________________*)
(*Initial conditions from M&W with u=0*)
(*--------------------------------*)
mumax = fmur0[R]; dmu = mumax/MP; k = pc/rho0^g0;
(*Parameters scales to normalise parameters*)
{rhoN, rN, mN, eN, uN} = {rho0 // N, 10^5, mumax, 10^-4 c^2, c};

G[mu_] := 4 \[Pi]*(rhoN rN^3)*rho[mu]*r[mu]^2*D[r[mu], mu]/mN(*MW39*);
p[mu_] := k*(rho[mu] rhoN )^g0(*MW40 *);
ep[mu_] := k*(rhoN*rho[mu])^(g0 - 1)/(g0 - 1);
w[mu_] := 1 + ep[mu]/c^2 + p[mu]/(rho[mu] rhoN c^2)(*MW41*);

(*introducing of equation*)
eq = {(4 \[Pi] rN^2*r[mu]^2*G[mu]/w[mu]*
       D[p[mu], mu]/mN + (m[mu]*gr mN/rN^2)/
       r[mu]^2 + (4 \[Pi]*gr rN)/c^2 p[mu]*r[mu]) == 0(*MW33*), 
   D[m[mu], mu]*mN == 
    4 \[Pi]*rhoN*rho[mu] (1 + ep[mu]/c^2) (rN*r[mu])^2*rN*
     D[r[mu], mu], G[mu] == Sqrt[1 - 2 mN*m[mu] gr/(rN*r[mu] c^2)]};
(*Variables,initial and boundary conditions*)
var = {rho, r, m(*,a,ep*)};
{dmu1, dmu3, mumax1} = {dmu, dmu2 = 0, mumax}/mN;
dr1 = FindRoot[fmur0[r] == dmu, {r, 10^6}][[1, 2]];

ic = {r[dmu1] == dr1/rN, m[dmu1] == fmr0[dr1]/mN, 
  rho[dmu1] == frhor0[dr1]/rhoN}; prec = 30;
{frho0, r0, fm0} = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic}, var, {mu, dmu1, mumax1}];
k = k/33;(*for particular calculation of initial data coldata_tov.dat*)
\

frho0 = Interpolation[
  Join[{{fmur0[dr]/mN, frhor0[dr]/rhoN}}, 
   Table[{mu, frho0[mu]}, {mu, dmu1, mumax1, (mumax1 - dmu1)/(MP)}]], 
  InterpolationOrder -> prec];
fmr0 = NDSolveValue[{4 \[Pi]*
      frhor0[r] (1 + k*(frhor0[r]^(g0 - 1)/(g0 - 1))/c^2) r^2 == 
     m'[r], m[dr] == rho0 + (k*rho0^g0/c^2)/(g0 - 1)}, m, {r, dr, R}];
r0 = Interpolation[
   Join[{{fmur0[dr]/mN, dr}}, 
    Table[{mu, r0[mu]}, {mu, dmu1, mumax1, (mumax1 - dmu1)/MP}]]];
fm0 = Interpolation[
   Join[{{fmur0[dr]/mN, fmr0[dr]/mN}}, 
    Table[{fmur0[r]/mN, fmr0[r]/mN}, {r, dr1, R, (R - dr1)/MP}]]];

(*Relativistic hydrodynamical equations-collapse of star*)
G[mu_, t_] := 
  4 \[Pi]*(rhoN rN^3)*rho[mu, t]*r[mu, t]^2*
   D[r[mu, t], mu]/mumax(*MW39*);
p[mu_, t_] := k*(rho[mu, t] rhoN )^g0(*MW40 *);
ep[mu_, t_] := k*(rhoN*rho[mu, t])^(g0 - 1)/(g0 - 1);
w[mu_, t_] := 
  1 + ep[mu, t]/c^2 + p[mu, t]/(rho[mu, t] rhoN c^2)(*MW41*);

a[mu_, t_] := 1/w[mu, t];

(*introducing of equation*)
eq = {D[u[mu, t], 
     t] == (-a[mu, 
         t] (4 \[Pi] rN^2*r[mu, t]^2*G[mu, t]/w[mu, t]*
          D[p[mu, t], mu]/mN + (gr mN/rN^2)*
          m[mu, t]/r[mu, t]^2 + (4 \[Pi]*gr rN)/c^2 p[mu, t]*
          r[mu, t]))/c^2(*MW33*), 
   D[r[mu, t], t] == a[mu, t]*u[mu, t]/rN(*MW34*), 
   D[rho[mu, t] r[mu, t]^2, t] == -a[mu, t]*rho[mu, t]*
     r[mu, t]^2 D[u[mu, t], mu]/D[r[mu, t], mu]/rN, 
   D[m[mu, t], t] == -4 \[Pi]/c^2*rN^3/mN*p[mu, t]*
     r[mu, t]^2 D[r[mu, t], t](*MW12*)};

(*Variables, initial and boundary conditions*)
var = {u, rho, r, m(*,a,ep*)};
ic = {u[mu, 0] == 0., r[mu, 0] == r0[mu ], m[mu, 0] == fm0[mu ], 
   rho[mu, 0] == frho0[mu]};
bc = {u[dmu2, t] == 0, m[dmu2, t] == fm0[dmu2], 
   rho[mumax1, t] == frho0[mumax1]};

tm = 6*10^-1; tm = 3.07*10^7; Dynamic[
 "time: " <> 
  ToString[CForm[{currentTime, Round[currentTime/c, 10^-7]}]]]
(*good results with DiffOr\[Rule]8 for MP=2000, lower than interpol \
initial funcitons*)
AbsoluteTiming[
  sol = Reap[
     NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc, 
       WhenEvent[Abs[Max@Im[rho[mu, t]]/Max@Re[rho[mu, t]]] > 1.1, 
        "StopIntegration"]}, var, {mu, dmu1, mumax1}, {t, 0., tm}, 
      InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
      Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "DiscretizedMonitorVariables" -> True, 
        Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
          "MinPoints" -> MP, "MaxPoints" -> MP, 
          "DifferenceOrder" -> 10}}, 
      EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = t;), 
      StepMonitor :> Sow[t/c]]];];
{fu, frho, fr, fm(*,fa,fm*)} = sol[[1]]; tm = currentTime;
{my1 = Plot[
   Evaluate[Table[-Log10[-Re[fu[mu/21, t]]], {t, {3*10^7, tm}}]], {mu,
     2 dmu1*21, mumax1*21}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 1}},
    FrameLabel -> {"fu", currentTime/c}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
   PlotStyle -> Dashed],
 my2 = Plot[
   Evaluate[
    Table[Log10[rhoN Re[frho[mu/21, t]]], {t, {3*10^7, tm}}]], {mu, 
    dmu1*21, mumax1*21}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> {"frho"}, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotStyle -> Dashed],
 my3 = Plot[
   Evaluate[Table[Log10[Re[fr[mu/21, t]]], {t, {3*10^7, tm}}]], {mu, 
    dmu1*21, mumax1*21}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> {"fr"}, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotStyle -> Dashed],
 my4 = Plot[
   Evaluate[Table[Re[fm[mu, t]], {t, {3*10^7, tm}}]], {mu, dmu1, 
    mumax1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"fm"}, 
   ImageSize -> Medium]}
```

[image]
Correct solution with times in seconds, time scale in my calculations is t = time*c (c-speed of light)

Comment: Without the specific code sample it's hard to give advice. Please show us a [minimal working example](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/1871).

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for your comment. I added a link to all my code. It seemed like a general problem of solving the initial conditions, so I didn't share the code.

Comment: Please don't provide the code via external link, because the link can easily be broken. If the code is too long to post here, it should be properly simplified.

Comment: No problem, now there is also code.

Comment: 1. Once again, you should simplify your sample as much as possible, for example, why do you include `tsteps` in your sample? 2. How is the _correct solution_ obtained? 3. Can you add more background information?

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for your time and interest. 1) If the code is to work, I can really delete only the tsteps line, I overlooked it in the many things I deleted. 2) and 3) The "correct solution" comes from an old fortran program that solves the same problem with the same equations and is published in this article: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8wkoc7uaz0pw2ot/may_white.pdf?dl=0 . It's a more complicated problem, I don't want to burden anyone. I just need to know how to generally treat boundary conditions when it is practically impossible to enter $u [0, t] == 0$.

Comment: 1. The two `Needs[…]` at the begining, `my1=…` and the last `Plot` are redundant, there may be more. 2. If this system is actually defined in spherical coordinate system and there exists a removable singularity at $r=0$, then the b.c. at $r=0$ is usually implicitly included in the system. ([Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192980/1871) is an example, it's about polar coordinate, but the underlying issue is similar. )

Comment: @xzczd Thank you again, but this example is out of me. I don't understand that problem so I can't extact issue about $r==0$ and implement to my problem. Could you please suggest how to do it in my spherical symmetric problem, where I don't use $\theta$?

Comment: That depends on the underlying physics. One common case is, if the unknown function (say $u$) is smooth at $r=0$, then we have $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{r}}\big|_{r=0}=0$. Another common case is, if `mumax1` is an approximation of $\infty$, and $u$ vanishes at $\infty$, then we have $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{r}}\big|_{r=\infty}=0$.

Comment: Understand, in my case the problem is hydrodynamic of star and its collapse. Independent variable is baryonic mass - mu (it makes sense rather than radius r) and unknown functions than are fr[mu,t] - radius at mu and time, frho[mu,t] - density at mu and time, fm[mu,t] - gravitational mass at mu and time and if it moves (collapses) fu[mu,t] - velocity of fall at mu and time. So fr fm and fu ->0 as mu ->0 and frho -> 0 asmu-> mumax1 -> surface. mu=0 is center and mu=mumax1 is surface of the star. Does it help?

Comment: Things may be troublesome. If one takes a closer look to the system, it's not hard to notice that only `bc[[1]]` and `bc[[3]]` is needed to uniquely determined a solution in principle. But, if the original paper has actually made use of all 4 b.c.s you mentioned in the last comment, given that _shocks_ and _artificial viscosity_ is mentioned, I won't be surprised if technique as shown in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133131/1871), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133140/1871) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197305/1871) is used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107669/discussion-between-vrbic-and-xzczd).